# Where are the constraints in Xcode 8.2.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I'm working on replacing iAds with AdMob and I'm following the Google instructions found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start), but I don't know where the constraints are located on Xcode.

Where are the constraints in Xcode 8.2.1?

The picture from the instructions states they are located on the bottom, but I don't see the icons in the most recent Xcode version.

[image: Xcode 8.2.1]

The screenshot where the constraints are supposedly located:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need to enable auto layout to see it.